# How to rotate a view at React-native by webview method

Tags: react-native

I made webview method by react native.
The webview homepage is loaded well using 'expo-cli'.
But the problem is the webview doesn't be rotate by landscapde mode of my device.
How can I solve this problem? Thank you so much.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return <WebView source={{ uri: 'http://111.111.111.111/web' }} />;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your `app.json` file. Blank apps created with Expo get the value `orientation: portrait` by default. You can change it to `default`.
Expo docs: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/#orientation